# LoadError: cannot load such file -- english

Tags: ruby

Our code does

```
require "english"
```

It worked locally, but we got this error on our CI server:

> LoadError: cannot load such file -- english

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out the fix was to change

```
require "english"
```

into

```
require "English"
```

Our local OS X file system (where the first one worked) was case-insensitive. But the CI server has a case-sensitive Linux file system that only accepts `"English"` with a capital E.