# Configuration error LoadError: cannot load such file -- chef_handler_foreman (require statement in /etc/chef/client.rb)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, redhat, chef-recipe, theforeman

I am trying to register existing chef-nodes to Foreman. I followed:

https://www.theforeman.org/plugins/foreman_chef/0.5/index.html

This tells me to install chef_handler_foreman gem and put the following in /etc/chef/client.rb:

> require 'chef_handler_foreman'
>
> foreman_server_options  'https://your.proxy.server:8443'
>
> foreman_facts_upload    true
>
> foreman_reports_upload  true
>
> foreman_enc             true

I did both.

When I run chef-client , I get:

> [root@ip-10-139-67-124 chef]# chef-client
>
> [2017-06-29T13:25:09-04:00] FATAL: Configuration error LoadError: cannot load such file -- chef_handler_foreman
>
> [2017-06-29T13:25:09-04:00] FATAL:   /etc/chef/client.rb:4:in `from_string'
>
> [2017-06-29T13:25:09-04:00] FATAL: Aborting due to error in '/etc/chef/client.rb'
>
> [root@ip-10-139-67-124 chef]#

Here is the evidence that I have the gem installed:

> [root@ip-10-139-67-124 chef]# gem list | grep chef
>
> chef_handler_foreman (0.2.0)

I am running Redhat 7.3.

I have looked into the following question and few others. Answers to those suggest a case-sensitivity problem, which is not the case here:

> [LoadError: cannot load such file -- english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294172/loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-english)

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please run with `knife --verbose --verbose` to get the full traceback.

Comment: Try `/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem list | grep foreman` I suspect you have the gem installed in your system ruby and not in chef's ruby.

Comment: bingo! @Tensibai . That was it! Thank you! If you submit it as answer, I will mark it as such. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @coderanger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check with `/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem list | grep foreman`.

I suspect you have the gem installed in your system ruby and not in chef's ruby bundled in the omnibus installer to avoid clashs with system ruby.

Usually you should use chef to install gem inside chef and configure itself.
Install gems with the `chef_gem` resource and take advantage of the `chef_client` cookbook to configure chef.